# Use logback to log SQL parameters in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, logback, jdbctemplate

I'm using *Logback* with *Spring JdbcTemplate* to log my SQL queries. My configurations contains next line:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" level="DEBUG" />
```

But this logs only query with wildcards `?` without list of parameters.

Here on SO I found a few answers how to achieve parameters logging with *log4j*. But I don't want to switch to *log4j*.

So how can I receive parameters list for *JdbcTemplate* with *Logback*?

**Edit**

Actually, I'm using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, if it matters.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

`<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="TRACE" />`

this will show log:

*Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1234], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type unknown*

Comment: It's a bit verbose, but it gets the job done in an out-of-the-box sort of way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer handling SQL statement logging at the DataSource or JDBC driver level.

I use [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) DataSource/Connection Pool library, which include support for statement logging via `SLF4J` and many other usefull [features](http://jolbox.com/features.html).

If changing your DataSource/Connection Pool library is not an option, maybe you can use [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) which works as a proxy jdbc driver, which logs statements to `SLF4J` before calling the actual jdbc driver that talks to the database.

Answer (score 0):

We can use as follow :

org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.

See Link: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-logging-guide/

Comment: `<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE" additivity="false" >
             <appender-ref ref="jdbc-transaction-log"/>
         </logger>`

Comment: Please [edit] according to [answer], using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and add the info from comments to the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the spring boot version is lower than 5.1 you will not get results. The parameters and the query are treated as separate objects, so the only result you will find in your log will be something like "....AND (A.COD)=TRIM(?)" Extending NamedParameterJdbcTemplate I think is the only solution.